# web2py: DAL find() not working

Tags: web2py, data-access-layer

**tl;dr:** read the last paragraph

I have a function which is supposed to return three `row` objects in a list. And the row objects are as following:

- row from table `mining`
- belongs to the current `savestate`
- `process` is either 1, 2 or 3, respectively for the three members in the list
- of those the one with the biggest `finish_date`

The minings have no direct relationship with savestates, so I have to trace the correct savestate through table called `turn`. The relationships are as follows: savestate 1:n turn 1:1 mining.

This is what I have so far:

```
def get_latest_minings(save_id):
    return_list = []
    #get all turn.ids that belong to this savestate:
    savestate_turns = [s.id for s in db(db.turn.savestate_id == save_id).select(db.turn.id)]
    #get all minings that belong to these turns:
    save_minings = db(db.mining.turn_id.belongs(savestate_turns)).select()
    #loop to get three objects:
    for i in range(1,4):
        #from save_minings, get all minings, whose process is i:
        line_minings = save_minings.find(lambda row: row.process == i)
        #initialize loop variables:
        latest_date = 0
        latest = None
        #loop to find the biggest finish_date:
        for m in line_minings:
            if m.finish_date > latest_date:
                latest_date = m.finish_date
                latest = m
        #add the row with the biggest finish_date to the list:
        return_list.append(latest)
    #return locals() for testing purposes:
    return locals()
    #actual return:
    #return return_list
```

This however doesn't work as intended. This is what it returns:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ns6mq9414vw25s9/get_latest_minings.png?dl=0

I have run some separate tests and **I have found the problem to be with the line**: `line_minings = save_minings.find(lambda row: row.process == i)`. Every other line works as it should. What is wrong here? Another question: can this be optimized more? I'm particularly curious about tracing the correct savestate.

Answer (score 1):

1. On your first question `What is wrong here?`:
   Is it possible that the field type of the process is set to `string` or `text` or anything other than `integer`?
2. Your second question `can this be optimized more?`: yes. probably.

Without the rest of your code at hand, here's a shot:

```py
def get_latest_minings(save_id):
    # from the minings that belong to this savestate:
    query = (db.mining.turn_id == db.turn.id) & (db.turn.savestate_id == save_id)

    # [optional] if you want to restrict the process ids only to be 1,2 or 3. 
    # given your output, you only have 1 and 2 so it would be useless 
    # again, mind the datatype, don't compare strings to integers. 
    # but for completion, i'll stick to your original functionality
    query &= (db.mining.process.belongs([1,2,3]))

    # get the latest finish date per mining process
    maxdate = db.mining.finish_date.max()
    save_minings = db(query).select(maxdate, db.mining.process, groupby=db.mining.process)

    # create a lookup structure with processid as key
    last_date_lookup = {row.mining.process:row[maxdate] for row in save_minings}
    # query the lookup structure per process id or None if not available
    return [last_date_lookup.get(pid) for pid in range(1,4)]
```

It's untested of course, and not even parsed or anything but I hope it helps.

Also remember there might be an error about web2py's DAL not being able to find a certain field. I've noticed the returned rows need to be queried differently when joined tables are queried. Mostly you can see this in `row.mining.process` where the table name is used instead of `row.process` which is perfectly use-able when querying only the `mining` table.